# Row-based security in Postgresql 9.4 based on views for read and write access

Tags: postgresql, view, postgresql-9.4

For a system, where the users have full shell access, we want to manage the folders shared between the users via access control lists, using an postgresql database. Therefore each user has an personal database account and we use row based security based on views. Here is our current draft:

```
REVOKE ALL ON jobs_admin FROM public;
REVOKE ALL ON share_admin FROM public;

CREATE VIEW share
WITH (security_barrier)
AS
SELECT *
FROM share_admin
WHERE username = current_user
OR owner = current_user
WITH CHECK OPTION;

CREATE VIEW jobs_read
WITH (security_barrier)
AS
SELECT *
FROM jobs_admin j, share_admin s
WHERE s.username = current_user
AND j.project LIKE s.project || '%'
WITH CHECK OPTION;

CREATE VIEW jobs_write
WITH (security_barrier)
AS
SELECT *
FROM jobs_admin j, share_admin s
WHERE (s.username = current_user
AND s.permission = 'w'
AND j.project LIKE s.project || '%')
OR j.project LIKE current_user || '%'
WITH CHECK OPTION;

ALTER VIEW share OWNER TO admin;
ALTER VIEW jobs_read OWNER TO admin;
ALTER VIEW jobs_write OWNER TO admin;

GRANT ALL ON share TO public;
GRANT SELECT ON jobs_read TO public;
GRANT ALL ON jobs_write TO public;

RESET ROLE;
```

Now we have two issues:

1. A user could add the entry '/' to his share view and share this folder with himself, then he would be able to see all database entries of all other users.
2. At the moment we need to switch in our interface between the jobs_read and jobs_write table.

So I thought about using triggers like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_trigger
  INSTEAD OF INSERT ON jobs_read
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_trigger_func();

CREATE FUNCTION insert_trigger_func() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $BODY$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO jobs_write VALUES (NEW.*);
  RETURN NEW;
END; $BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

but while this is easy for the insert statement, it is much more complicated for UPDATE and DELETE.

As all this feels rather buggy, I was wondering if anybody could point me to an good example or some book which handles these topics.

Best

Jan

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to do, but you create the profile in db, but the display/write restriction is part of the UI not of the DB.

Comment: Why not update to 9.5 or 9.6 and use built-in RLS?